# Axon Saga not getting created

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, axon

I have an spring boot application that uses the axon framework
The database to store the axon tables (*saga_entry*, *domain_event_entry*, *association_value_entry* ...) are persisted in Postgres (not using axon server)

for some reason this particular Saga is not being created (it used to work normally for long time up until recently)

```
@StartSaga()
@SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = JOB_ID)
public void onVersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent(VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent event) {
    log.info("Version Refresh Job Created With job Id: {}", event.getJobId());
        ...
}
```

I launched several jobs (each one an instance of the aggregate) and all of them did not continue to reach the saga

I checked the *domain_event_entry* table to see if the event (the one that created the saga) is getting published

```
SELECT *
FROM domain_event_entry
WHERE payload_type = 'VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent'
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC;
```

```
2785210 24023a4e-fa93-4c5d-a3fe-a267849f302e    43014637    43014638        VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent   2021-03-04T18:19:01.787Z    83309b8c-4d75-4ed9-bd41-e5dfd824a28e    0   VersionRefreshAggregate
2784852 0f0e8e89-5a9a-4133-93e5-0f9ae155ee29    43009375    43009376        VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent   2021-03-04T17:20:47.441Z    0cdd5b5f-be40-479a-a8a3-888bf7088188    0   VersionRefreshAggregate
2784851 064e538b-b561-4a31-a494-1916a6434233    43009351    43009352        VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent   2021-03-04T17:20:42.196Z    3a371eb8-32aa-4664-8a82-16f375b9f4e9    0   VersionRefreshAggregate
2784711 e6c5da48-3145-4f16-aabf-c9eba442e04f    43007446    43007447        VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent   2021-03-04T17:00:53.527Z    b381ef87-9ca9-4cc1-9b1a-f93321f3fee3    0   VersionRefreshAggregate
2784580 cd4fe64e-dd25-459e-ac57-d4d46c521e8c    43005436    43005437        VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent   2021-03-04T16:42:08.501Z    08924458-e931-4fec-b5d0-b6b117ebdd3a    0   VersionRefreshAggregate
2784075 fbd3c2da-d0ee-49a0-b1c3-26ad7c99ae8a    42997780    42997781        VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent   2021-03-04T15:23:36.404Z    08c0d2ce-9292-40a6-8add-81547be275d9    0   VersionRefreshAggregate
```

and found that the event payload_type = VersionRefreshJobCreatedEvent is being added normally
And there are other event handlers (projections for read model) that are listening to this event and working fine and getting invoked which means the evens are getting published normally

I queried the associations the see if the event the saga is getting creating but for some reason not responding the event or other events

```
SELECT *
FROM association_value_entry
where association_key = 'jobId'
  AND saga_type = 'com.integration.core.versionrefresh.VersionRefreshSaga'
  AND association_value = '${aggId}';
```

and found no associations created for these values

**All other sagas** in the application are **working normally** as well

**I restarted all the instances** of the application but that **didn't solve it**.

I deployed a **new instance** the **postgres database** and the saga started getting created and **worked** and the problem appeared to be **solved** (but when rehooking to the old instance its still not working)

The **restart** of the old instance is **not feasible** and the **rollout** as well.

There are **no logs** or exception being thrown in the app (by axon or spring boot) to debug

The command is getting launched and the aggregate is being created and raising the corresponding event but for some reason the saga is not getting created so the transaction is not starting

1- How can I know why the old postgress instance is not creating sagas? is the SagaEventProcessor refusing to process events?

2- How can it be solved?

thanks,

Comment: I would recommend following up Yvonne's response. Chances are indeed high that the `TrackingEventProcessor` processing events for this Saga, for whatever reason does not process new events. Either the token is too far ahead, or the token is claimed by another Java process hidden in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason for this behaviour is that the token of the Saga Processor is already at the head of the event stream, could you check the tokenstore table and find the corresponding processor?

```
SELECT * FROM token_entry WHERE processor_name = 'VersionRefreshSagaProcessor'
```

If the token is present and at the head of the event store and that's is unwanted behaviour you can set the token to the tail in order to handle all the events in the event store. See https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors#custom-tracking-token-position